# glyphicon- colour change issue

Tags: css, glyphicons

this is my first time using glyphs, but i know this much they are text, and can be styled just like any other text.
This is the reason I'm confused to why my glyphs icon is not changing colour.

I want it to change the colour from black(default) to white. This is my code:

HTML

```
<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span><a class="lolo" href="Franchise-Details.php"><b>Admin Panel</b></a></li>
```

CSS

```
.glyphicon glyphicon-cog{
color:  #fff;
margin-right: 2px;
}
```

where have a gone wrong? any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
.glyphicon.glyphicon-cog{
    color:  #fff;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

You have missed a `.` before the `glyphicon-cog` and also the space between the two classes is not required.

As the space indicates that `glyphicon` class named element is parent and `glyphicon-cog` named element is under this parent, which is not the case in your scenario.

Since you are targeting the same element with two classes the syntax should be

```
.classOne.classTwo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to override the colors of of your glyphs. You may need to use a different color for the same glyph elsewhere. Instead make a CSS class like:

```
.white
{ color: #fff; }
```

-and keep the margins to your "glyphicon" class, then reserve the "glyphicon-cog" class only for the data (before content *unicode) as this saves file-size because you do not need to define margins for every single glyph, only in the font-class: "glyphicon" -if required.

Then simply use in HTML as:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog white"></span>
```